# How do I download Wine 1.4?

Tags: software-installation, wine, downloads

When I try to go download Wine, It says "There isn’t a software package called “wine1.4” in your current software sources." I've already checked the Wiki page, but it says to just "install" it, which I cannot. Can anyone help me with this, I've already added the respository thing from the wine site, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Just checked the wine site, and 1.4 is available from their PPA. Head to your terminal, and add the PPA manually:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

Then update your APT package information by:

`sudo apt-get update`

You should then be able to install 1.4 with the following command in the Terminal:

`sudo apt-get install wine1.4`

Let me know if that works.

Comment: "Package wine1.4 is not available, but referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source"   "E: Package 'wine1.4' has no installation candidate"

Comment: Try installing the version 1.3 : `sudo apt-get install wine1.3`

Comment: Also didn't work.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install wine1.7` found on : http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wine

Comment: "sudo: apt-get-repository: command not found"